# How to configure netns in xx.yaml?

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, network-bridge

Running on Ubuntu 18.04.
Here is an example via command-line:

```
sudo ip netns add testBB
sudo ip netns list
sudo ip netns exec testBB ip link set vnet4 netns testBB
sudo ip netns exec testBB ip link set eno3.50 netns testBB
sudo ip netns exec testBB ip link set vnet4 up
sudo ip netns exec testBB ip link set eno3.50 up
```

But this is not permanent. I would like to set up above configuration in `/etc/netplan/eno3.yaml`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Netplan does not have any support for network namespaces at this time.  You would need to manage this elsewhere on the system, not as part of netplan yaml.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by implementing a script that runs through networkd-dispatcher.
Place it in /etc/networkd-dispatcher/xxx/, make it executable, and it should work.
It gets the system path to the interface as an argument. So what I do is:

```
IFACE=`basename "$1"`
```